# Authentication with both email and username (same field) (laravel API )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am building laravel API of my website . I am using laravel 5.3

I am using the API in building mobile app .

In login section, there are two fields :

1. Enter email or username
2. Enter password

In my DB , email and username are different columns.

Here is the function:

```
public function authenticate()
{

$credentials=request()->only('username','password');

try {

    $token=JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);

    if(!$token){
        return response()->json(['error'=>'credentials wrong'],401);
    }
}
catch(JWTException $e) {

 return response()->json(['error'=>'something_went_wrong'],500);

}
return response()->json(['token'=>$token],200);
}
```

Here only username is used,I want to use both username and password.

If need any other info please ask.

ty:)

Comment: you can see in this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/log-in-with-username-or-email-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL function
Like this:-

```
$login_type = filter_var( $data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ? 'email' : 'username';
```

And then pass in auth attempt function like this:-

```
Auth::attempt([$login_type => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']])
```

In your case:-

```
According to your Html you have used two input
<input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name="loginEmail" id="inputname"/>
<input type="password"required autocomplete="off" name="loginPassword" id="inputpassword"/>

And your function is:- 

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
$data = $request->all();
$login_type = filter_var( $data['loginEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ? 'email' : 'username';
//$credentials=request()->only('username','password');

try {

    $token=JWTAuth::attempt([$login_type => $data['loginEmail'], 'password' => $data['loginPassword']]);

    if(!$token){
        return response()->json(['error'=>'credentials wrong'],401);
    }
}
catch(JWTException $e) {

 return response()->json(['error'=>'something_went_wrong'],500);

}
return response()->json(['token'=>$token],200);
}
```

Hope it Helps!

In postman I was using key in the body called 'username' so here instead of loginEmail , username will come and it will work fine ! ty

Comment: there is no error....I implemented your code and try to login with email and password ..it worked fine but when I tried with username , it shows credentials wrong

Comment: https://paste.laravel.io/AnXEl  here is function....i am using postman to test my api

Comment: what is the name of input filed where you eneted email or username

Comment: if your asking of website html here it is: https://paste.laravel.io/onD58

Comment: check my updated answer make sure your table columns are email,username and password

Comment: this time got the error: `Undefined index: loginEmail`

Comment: when I did `dd($data); ` just getting email=>{email}, password=>{pass}

Comment: have you print the data like this this after $data  echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146018/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-kunal).

Comment: but your input name form email is loginEmail and for password is loginPassword  so it should be worked

Answer (score 0):

Override this method in your `AuthController`

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $login = $request->get('loginEmail');
    $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

    return [
        $field => $login,
        'password' => $request->get('password'),
    ];
}
```